# Magento2 plugin around listener not working

Tags: magento2, ajax, plugin

I want to override a method from a Ui component which sets filter values.
My Plugin code

```
<?php 

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugins\DataProvider\Product;

class GiftProvider
{
    public function aroundAddFilter(
          $subject,  
          \Closure  $proceed, 
          \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter
    )
    {
        if (isset($subject->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $subject->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
            ->addFilter(
                    $subject->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
            );
        } else {
            $abstractProvider::addFilter($filter);
        }

        if(!isset($subject->addFilterStrategies['is_gift']))
        {
            $subject->addFilterStrategies['is_gift']
                ->addFilter(
                    $subject->getCollection(),
                    'is_gift',
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => 1]);
        }
        return $subject;
    }

}
```

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <plugin name="gift_data_provider_around_plugin" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugins\DataProvider\Product\GiftProvider" sortOrder="1500" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Ajax returns

```
Fatal 500 Internal Server Error
```

And a message is outputted saying :

```
"Attention
Something went wrong."
```

What did go wrong is that the response of the ajax is empty when I inspect it.

Where is my mistake, Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters in aroundAddFilter of plugin must have like this

```
public function aroundAddFilter(
   \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,  
   \Closure $proceed, 
   \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter,
   \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider $abstractProvider
)
{
  //body code
  return $proceed($abstractProvider);
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: nope, didn't work, same thing....

Comment: re-check your controllers , blocks . It maybe some errors vars or miss something. Try remove last parameter in function `aroundAddFilter` and return only proceed
Could you find anything in var/log/exception? It may helpfuls for debug

Comment: in magento_root/var/log/ dorectory I have only debug.log  system.log , no exception, I checked the apache2 error log though... and we have  winner: "Cannot access protected property Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\ProductDataProvider\\Interceptor::$addFilterStrategies"

Comment: that sucks... I have to rewrite the whole class now ?

Comment: nvm dude, 10x for the help i will modify the question and mark your answer as correct. thank you one more time! I just used $filter setters to set the values I needed and called $proceed($filter) and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: nah... didn't work... i pass the filter it still shows all products...

Comment: but this is more like another question.. I will post it if i can't find a solution. Thank you.